Continuity of integral with parameter with signum function.
Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable (bounded) function. Show that the function
$$F(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)\text{sgn}(x-t)dt$$
is continuous.
What I did so far:
So that sgn(x-t) is either -1,1 or 0. The only "problem" this function has is for $x \in [0,1]$ because the integral has to deal with both -f(t) and f(t) on that interval. So I kinda defined a piecewise function like so:
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
        \int_{0}^{1}-f(t)dt &; x\in (-\infty,0)\\
        \int_{0}^{x}-f(t)dt + \int_{x}^{1}f(t)dt &; x\in [0,1]\\
        \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt &; x \in (1, \infty)\\
    \end{cases}$$
Is this ok? How do I show continuity of this now? I guess all 3 pieces are separately continuous because of the Fundemental theorem of Calculus but idk if thats enough.

You had the wrong function $F(x)$ over the interval $[0,1]$. When $0<t<x$, $\mathrm{sgn}(x-t)=1$, and when $x<t<1$, $\mathrm{sgn}(x-t)=-1$. Therefore, $F(x)$ on this interval should be rewrited as:
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t+\int_x^1 -f(t)\mathrm{d}t.$$
And now, for the continuity problem, to check if $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. We need to prove:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}F(x)=F(a).$$
Let's ignore the trivial case where $a\notin \{0,1\}$. When $a=0$, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}F(x)=\int_0^0 f(t)\mathrm{d}t+\int_0^1 -f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1 -f(t)\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}F(x)=F(0).$$
So $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. Similar things can be said at $x=1$.
Therefore, $F(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.
